# Trigger a js function to trigger a function in my controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scala

Im using scala for my project and I have a controller that have an action func that called:

```
def doSomething(url: String)
```

I want to run this function from the button I added in my `index.html`:

```
<md-button ng-hide="some condition" ng-click="" ng-model="selectedStack.outputs.someUrl">Run</md-button>
```

in the ng-model I have the url I want to pass `doSomething`.

What do I need to do to trigger `doSomething` from `ng-click`?

I have also a `main.controller.js` which controlles all the js functions, so I guess I need to create a function there to do that and pass it in the `ng-click`, but its not my project and I never done it, it would be great if someone could help me with this basic flow...thanks!!

the func `doSomething` is not part of the the `main.controller.js`....I have a scala class `myClass` and `doSomething` is a function in this class...so somewhere I need to create instance of `myClass` and only then trigger `doSomething`

Comment: can use `ng-click="doSomething(selectedStack.outputs.someUrl)"`

Answer (score 0):

You need the button to call a function in your controller

```
<md-button ng-hide="some condition" ng-click="ctrlFunction(selectedStack.outputs.someUrl)">Run</md-button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ctrlFunction= function(myUrl){
   // myUrl: would be set to http://localhost:80/doSomething
   $http.post(myUrl).then(function(data){ ... });
}
```

Comment: the func `doSomething` is not part of the the main.controller.js....I have a scala class `myClass` and `doSomething` is a function in this class...so somewhere I need to create instance of `myClass` and only then trigger `doSomething`...

Comment: Yes, that's why I am defining a `doSomething`function in the `$scope` of the controller and thus calling your scala method through an HTTP request which I assume is what your scala application listens to?

Comment: yes this is what im listening to, but I think maybe i got confused with the naming. so lets say my js func name is `doSomething`, and the scala class name is `myClass` and the func I want to trigger is `myFunc`...(in myClass). I dont see here in your axample acess to `myFunc`...

Comment: I updated my code. Also, you probably shouldn't have `url: string` as a parameters?